# how can orderby array in map firestore with flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("posting")
        .where("authorId", isEqualTo: widget.uid)
        //.orderBy("datetime")
        .snapshots(),
    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        return Container();
      }
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: snapshot.data!.size,
        physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          //return Container();

          return ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs[index["replyCount"],
            itemBuilder: (context, count) {
              return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('users')
                          .where("uid",
                              isEqualTo: snapshot.data!.docs[index]["reply"]
                                  [count]["replyId"])
                          .snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, replyUser) {
```

for example, user has some posts written by this user.
some other user reply his posting.
then I want to show user who was writing post can be check reply alarm. order by reply time
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I cannot see any `uid` property inside your document. Can you show it to us?

Comment: I was referring to the screenshot.

Comment: here! sorry i m not good at stackoverflow.i edit my question

Comment: "not working" is hard to help with. What does the code do? And what do you expect it to do instead? Also note that we have no way to know what the value of "snapshot.data!.docs[index]["reply"][count]["replyId"])` is, so it's best to reproduce the problem with a hard-coded value, and then show us that.

Comment: Ahah! I forgot it! I just change my firebase.using subcollection! Thank u for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work:

```
.orderBy("reply.datetime")
```

For one, there is no field `reply.datetime` in your document. There is only `reply[0].datetime`, but I doubt you can specify an array item like that.

The common use-case for what you're trying to do is to order the documents on their latest reply timestamp. For such cases, the idiomatic approach is to store the timestamp of the latest reply as a top-level field in your document (say `latestReplyDateTime`) and order on that field.